# Display RMB context menu for selected file using registry

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, registry, contextmenu

I've added below string under command node but when RMB on .prt file, option is not displayed. Please find below image and string value for command node. My machine is Windows 10.

**String:**

```
cmd.exe /s/c " @"C:\NX12\wntx64\kits\nxbin\ugpc.exe" -s -a "%1" & pause "
```

[image]

Comment: It is often prudent to count doublequotes to ensure you have matched pairs, _especially before posting it as problematic code in a question here_.

Comment: @Compo, thanks for correcting me, updated code.